# Allow only single instance of COM object

Tags: com, c++builder, c++builder-xe5

Is there a good way to enforce that only one instance of my COM object (served by an in-process server) may be created at any one time?

Currently I am creating a Windows Mutex in the constructor of TMyObjectImpl; and if the mutex already exists then I set a flag to put my object into a "dead" state: when this flag is set, all implementations of interface functions will return an error code.

I would like to throw an exception instead of creating a "dead" object like this, however it is not good to throw C++ exceptions across a COM boundary and I'm not sure if the C++Builder implementation of COM can cope with this reliably.

There are actually two possible problem scenarios:

- The same process creates two of MyObject
- Two different processes create one each of MyObject

The Mutex guards against both of these.

My object factory function is:

```
static void createFactory()
{
    new TCppAutoObjectFactory<TMyObjectImpl>(Comserv::GetComServer(),
                       __classid(TMyObjectImpl),
                       CLSID_MyObject,
                       Comobj::ciMultiInstance,
                       Comobj::tmSingle);
}
#pragma startup createFactory 32
```

According to the C++Builder DocWiki, setting the Instancing property has no effect for in-process servers - it always behaves like `ciMultiInstance` even if you specify `ciSingleInstance`.

My object needs this property because it access global resources (e.g. writes to a file in a specific disk location); the semantics of the object are such that there is only supposed to be one open at a time. I'm not looking to add support for multiple instances of my object.

Comment: My guess is that Delphi/C++ Builder catches exceptions when constructing an object in its `IClassFactory::CreateInstance` and returns a failure `HRESULT`, have you tried it?

Comment: I'll trawl through the source and see if I can find something reliable. (The single best feature of C++Builder is that they give you all the source code for all the VCL and runtime libraries, so you can answer questions like this and fix bugs yourself)